# appand formData and state values into single array and pass throgh axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, form-data

I am trying to pass values in `allvalues` and formData into a single array and pass it through `axios`.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
        allValues: {
            name: "",
            class: "",
            school: ""
        },
    }
}
```

```
let formData = new FormData();
axios
  .post(
    'url',
    formData, //appand formdata and allValues

    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(`Success` + res.data);
  });
```

Comment: From the question, it is not clear what is the problem or error you are encountering, can you please explain it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a complex object structure or an array of some sort through, you need to `jsonify` your data.

Here is how you can pass `allValues` in your request:

```
formData.append("allValues", JSON.stringify(this.state.allValues))
```

Keep in mind that you will need to convert the `json` back to whatever it is you need on your backend (for example, in node it would convert back to a `JS object`, in python it would convert to a `dictionary` etc)